# Use different subquery depending on variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am trying to change the subquery used in the expression, depending on the value of a variable I am passing to the sql.

I have tried a few different ways with no success. The following sql throws the error: subquery must return only one column

```
WITH
sel_cells As (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN cast (RIGHT( variable, 1 ) As int)>1 THEN (
            SELECT part_2.geom, part_2.gridcode
            FROM adm2 AS part_1, grid_1km_europe AS part_2
            WHERE part_1.gid = 7224
            AND ST_Intersects(part_1.geom, part_2.geom)
        ) ELSE (
            SELECT part_2.geom, part_2.gridcode
            FROM grid_1km_europe As part_2
            INNER JOIN grid_1km_europe_adm2 As part_1
            ON part_1.gridcode = part_2.gridcode
            WHERE part_1.adm_gid = 7224
        )
        END
),
emissions_part As (
    SELECT grid_id_1km, emissions_kg
    FROM emissions
    WHERE year_ = 2015 AND sector = 'Energy' AND pollutant = 'PM10'
)
SELECT
    a.emissions_kg,
    a.grid_id_1km,
    b.geom
FROM emissions_part As a
INNER JOIN sel_cells As b 
ON a.grid_id_1km = b.gridcode
```

I am using Postgres.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This query is quite big..can you specify with which portion of query you are having issue?

Comment: The problem is at the sel_cells part. If I didn't use CASE and instead had one of the two subqueries, the query would work fine.

Comment: Please share the tables and the output you desire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
with sel_cells As (
      select part_2.geom, part_2.gridcode
      from adm2 AS part_1 join
           grid_1km_europe as part_2
           on ST_Intersects(part_1.geom, part_2.geom)
      where part_1.gid = 7224 and
            right(variable, 1)::int > 1
      union all
      select part_2.geom, part_2.gridcode
      from grid_1km_europe As part_2 inner join
           grid_1km_europe_adm2 As part_1
           on part_1.gridcode = part_2.gridcode
      where part_1.adm_gid = 7224 and
            right(variable, 1)::int <= 1
     )
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this would be with plpgsql. Create a function that builds the query dynamically based on the variable, and returns you the records:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1(some_var BOOLEAN)
        RETURNS TABLE (g INTEGER, h INTEGER) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
                'WITH x AS ('
                || CASE WHEN some_var THEN
                        'SELECT g AS g, g AS h FROM generate_series(1, 5) g'
                   ELSE
                        'SELECT g AS g, g AS h FROM generate_series(6, 10) g'
                   END
                || ')
                SELECT g.*, x.h
                FROM generate_series(1, 10) g
                INNER JOIN x ON g.g = x.g';
END
$BODY$
        LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Then `SELECT * FROM f1(TRUE)` returns:

[image]

And `SELECT * FROM f1(FALSE)` returns:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I can do that, since the sql is stored in Geoserver as sql view

Comment: I have no idea what Geoserver is. What does it mean in as far as what you can and can't do?

Comment: It means that I cannot call a function (probably, not 100% sure). Like I said in another comment, the query will work without the CASE. I need a correct syntax that would allow me change the subquery depending on the variable. Is this something not possible??

Comment: If this is a view, how are you using a variable in it? Where's that variable coming from?

Comment: Without going into details, I can pass variables from my code to Geoserver, before the query is executed.

Comment: Can't you just change the view or whatever it is to (assuming it's a view) `CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM the_new_function(variable)`?